# How to decide if value in row is valid or not based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in dataframe and want to check if the **Year** is valid or not if present in between start_year AND end_year

```
Year      start_year      end_year    
2010        2012            2014
2013        2012            2015
2015        2015            2016
2009        2010            2012
2017        2016            2019
```

I want to add one more column (valid/invalid) specifying that the **Year** is valid or not

```
Year      start_year      end_year     valid/invalid 
2010        2012            2014         invalid
2013        2012            2015         valid 
2015        2015            2016         valid
2009        2010            2012         invalid 
2017        2016            2019         valid
```

How can we achieve this using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)

```
df["valid/invalid"] = np.where(df.Year.between(df.start_year,df.end_year),'valid','invalid')
df
   Year  start_year  end_year valid/invalid
0  2010        2012      2014       invalid
1  2013        2012      2015         valid
2  2015        2015      2016         valid
3  2009        2010      2012       invalid
4  2017        2016      2019         valid
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `np.where`

```
df['v/inv'] = np.where((df.Year>=df.start_year) & (df.Year<=df.end_year), 'valid','invalid')
df
Out[360]: 
   Year  start_year  end_year    v/inv
0  2010        2012      2014  invalid
1  2013        2012      2015    valid
2  2015        2015      2016    valid
3  2009        2010      2012  invalid
4  2017        2016      2019    valid
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to only using Pandas, then try the following solution which uses `apply` and `replace` -

```
df['valid/invalid'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.Year>=x.start_year) and (x.Year<=x.end_year), axis=1).replace({True:'Valid',False:'Invalid'})
```

```
   Year  start_year  end_year valid/invalid
0  2010        2012      2014       Invalid
1  2013        2012      2015         Valid
2  2015        2015      2016         Valid
3  2009        2010      2012       Invalid
4  2017        2016      2019         Valid
```

The first `apply` step gets you True or False if the year is in between (inclusive on both ends) the start and end year. Second step replaces the `True` and `False` with `Valid` or `Invalid` strings.

Comment: `pd.np.where()`